# SQL Partition Switching in OLTP server

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, database-partitioning

I have situation in my OLTP database table which i need your assistance. I use Sql server 2008 R2 edition. I have a table with more than 12 million records. I have done partition depending on the auto increment id.

Performance got increased after partition. but still we need to improve on insert of data into table. I was planing to do a partition switch . Will it help me out. ? How should i plan ?

My table is one of the core table in our database. So how i will handle the partition switch in live environment. There are loads of SP and calculations based on this table. So renaming or split into archive tables is not an option for me.

I am basically a SQL developer and we dont have any specialized DBA to help me out. So Any help will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: This particular table is a part of ERP which was shipped by a vendor. I am now recruited at clients place to rectify issue raised by the vendor. So there are plenty of SP need to be modified to improve the performance. Instead of finding and editing each SP i was trying to explore any better options.

My table schema contains 35 columns in which most if them are int type but also contain varchar fields too. Indexing is applied as per the SQL execution plans which has give a big boost in performance. if required i can provide full table structure and index details

Comment: But you will need to pick up more of a DBA mindset for this sort of task. As such, I think the question might be a better fit on the [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Partitioning isn't a performance feature. And 12M rows isn't all that much anyway. You haven't provided *any* information that could help imporove performance. What is the table's schema? What to the queries look like? Any Indexes? Any long running transactions or bad queries? Slow disks? Slow CPUs? What do the execution plans look like? Have you checked Activity Monitor for expensive queries, waits?

Comment: 12m is a small table. OTOH partition switches for active data with SP's attached smells like a desaster, they are specialized tools for large data warehouses. I would suggest getting into "I am a dba" mindset (and this sis tuff a SQL developer SHOULD know) and starting finding out where the performance is lost (analysis, execution plans) because I fail to see the problem in the first place if you properly tune your small database.

Comment: BTW designing the database *is* part of the the job of a SQL Developer. Administration is also a part of it. You can't design a good schema or a good query if you don't understand about indexes, performance tuning and troubleshooting.

Comment: @TomTom so you don't suggest to have partition switch in OLTP environment. right ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am trying to play my part but need a support from professionals like you.

Comment: @user3431700, you might be able to perform an incremental load from a staging table using `SPLIT` and `SWITCH` but the indexes would need to be aligned and a brief schema modification lock will be required. If inserts are performed outside the load process, avoiding identity collisions will be tricky. I suggest you continue query/index tuning instead of relying on table partitioning as a magic bullet to solve performance issues.

Comment: @user3431700 No, paticularly not for small tables like 12 million rows. And why do you need help from professionals when you CLAIM: "I am basically a SQL developer" - that is like a car mechanic needing help changing brakes. As Paganagiotis said, you should know this stuff given the credentials you claim. Knowing how to optimize performance is developer work.